# How to make emscripten to generate better code

Tags: javascript, c++, optimization, emscripten, asm.js

I have read lots about how fast Emscripten code can be, thus I decided to convert my js application to C++ and then compile to Emscripten. I got about +30% speed increase and it's not the thing I expected! (I thought it will be at least 5x speed increase) So I decided to check the compiled code and I saw this strange thing!

This is an original method code (C++, but it looks almost the same in the original "slow" JS application).

```
void Op2B()
{
    sm = (sm - 1) & 65535;
    t->time += 2;
}
```

This is an emscripten-compiled asm.js version of the same code

```
function __ZN16EpsilonGames_VGS3Z804Op2BEv($0) {
    $0 = $0|0;
    var $1 = 0, $10 = 0, $2 = 0, $3 = 0, $4 = 0, $5 = 0, $6 = 0, $7 = 0, $8 = 0, $9 = 0, label = 0, sp = 0;
    sp = STACKTOP;
    STACKTOP = STACKTOP + 16|0; if ((STACKTOP|0) >= (STACK_MAX|0)) abortStackOverflow(16|0);
    $1 = $0;
    $2 = $1;
    $3 = ((($2)) + 24|0);
    $4 = load4($3);
    $5 = (($4) - 1)|0;
    $6 = $5 & 65535;
    $7 = ((($2)) + 24|0);
    store4($7,$6);
    $8 = load4($2);
    $9 = load4($8);
    $10 = (($9) + 2)|0;
    store4($8,$10);
    STACKTOP = sp;return;
}
```

As you can see, It's far away from being optimal.

Is there any possibility to make this code a bit more optimal? I still hope to get at least x5 increase in speed.

Thanks!

Comment: *How* did you compile it? Which options did you use? Did you actually turn on optimizations?

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh, thank you. I've tried -O2 before, however, I got the error and I have sticked with no optimization mode. Now I've tried -O2 again, fixed the error and got a bit more clear code!
https://e-wm.org/i/E20181020-165904-001.png
Unfortunately, the speed of the code still the same - around +30% from the original code. Is it possible to get more?

Comment: Assuming your time measurements are indeed correct I don't think you can get much more improvement on such simple code. You may get some performance boost from targetting WebAssembly instead of asm.js, but it's also possible that the code you provided already gets optimized heavily by the JavaScript runtime so that your performance gain is smaller

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you. I also see some room for optimizations of the C++ code. I see there are lots of addressing to INT while I only need BYTE. Also I think I could remove Offset parameter by converting classes to set of raw C functions (bad way, but it should work better).